# Admin login problems. What are the correct settings of Session Cookie Management and Session Validation Management?

Tags: admin, login, session, cookie, validation

What are the correct settings for Session Cookie Management and Session Validation Management?

- In a single store setup
- In a multi store setup

**Session Management**

- Cookie Path
- Cookie Domain
- Use HTTP Only
- Cookie Restriction Mode

**Session Validation Settings**

- Validate REMOTE_ADDR
- Validate HTTP_VIA
- Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
- Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT
- Use SID on Frontend

I always have admin login problems. And can only get rid of it by editing the core file (comment out):
/files/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php

```
    // session cookie params
    $cookieParams = array(
        'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
        'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
        // 'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
        // 'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
        // 'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
    );
```

I guess there is no "correct" setting, otherwise there won't be any options. But what is the most common setting? Do I have to have different cookie paths for different stores? What could cause my problem (can't login in Magento admin).

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"I always have admin login problems" is a bit vague but here goes

Under `System > Configuration > Web` the settings should be as follows

[image]

Also set "Session Lifetime (seconds)" under `System > Configuration > Admin` to a high value like **7200** so you don't need to login repeatedly

Comment: Sander: thank you!

Comment: @Sander Mangel: I have the same config as you said but then as well I am unable to login to admin section after first log-out. I noticed in cookies that there are 2 cookies set for adminhtml and deleting one helps me to get rid of that issue but why that happens? Any idea?